# FireStore - LimitToLast is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I've been trying to make a prevButton for a pagination, using firestore and trying to use **limitToLast()**.
When I run the code I get an error saying ***limitToLast is not a function***.

```
Uncaught TypeError: db.collection(...).orderBy(...).endBefore(...).limitToLast is not a function
```

My code:

```
prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    db.collection('posts')
        .orderBy('likes', 'asc')
        .endBefore(firstDocument) // <-- The first document on view
        .limitToLast(3) // <-- LimitToLast is not a function ???
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => loadDocuments(snapshot));
});
```

If I remove limitToLast() my code runs without error, but of course it doesn't work as intended.

Gods of stackoverflow, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`limitToLast` is a method on the Firebase **Realtime Database** API. You are accessing Cloud Firestore, which has a separate (though sometimes similar) API.

The only method to limit results on Firestore is `limit(...)`. If you want the same behavior as `limitToLast` from Realtime Database, you'll have to:

1. Reverse the sort order
2. Limit to the correct number of results
3. Reverse the results client-side

Answer (score 3):

This is the code I made based on Frank's answer, in case someone finds it useful.

```
prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    db.collection('posts')
        .orderBy('likes', 'desc') // Reverse the sort order
        .startAfter(firstDoc) // First doc in view
        .limit(postPorPagina) // Limit the results
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            const documents = snapshot.docs.reverse(); // Reverse the documents again
            renderDocuments(documents); // Function that renders my documents on screen.
        });
});
```